# Integrate user_meta with iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I'm working on wordpress and need a custom code on a template page. I have to insert an iframe code to place the video chat by appear.in as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://appear.in/pmontalto" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The screenshot shows how the videochat appears in the page.

[image]

Now, on appear.in every user has his own room. In the code above the room for that user is "pmontalto".

What I need to accomplish is this. I would like to have the appear.in link in the  to be auto populate with the user username. Not the current username but that specific user who got registered.

So, the workflow is this. I register with username johndoe and the resume page is created. The appear.in iframe code for that specific resume page should be

```
<iframe src="https://appear.in/johndoe" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Only that part of the link should be updated. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using the author meta:

```
<iframe src="https://appear.in/<?php the_author_meta( 'user_login'); ?>" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```